# Laravel: import from csv file to database with extra columns

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I have two problems, first that I have csv file and want to import it to database, the **first problem** is in database I have id columns witch will be auto increment and not exists in csv file, and there are 2 others columns (name,job) are not exist on csv file but want them to be empty in database and end user will fill these fields
**second problem** is the format date in database is yyyy-mm-dd and its different to csv.
please note that I don't want to modify the csv file I want every thing to be done on laravel, can you help me

**controller of uploading csv**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
$upload=$request->file('upload-file');
$filePath=$upload->getRealPath();
$file=fopen($filePath,'r');
$header=fgetcsv($file);

$escapedHeader=[];
foreach ($header as $key => $value) {
$header=strtolower($value);

$escapedItem=preg_replace('/[^a-z]/','', $header);
array_push($escapedHeader, $escapedItem);

}
 while($columns=fgetcsv($file))
 {
  if($columns[0]=="")
  {
    continue;
  }
   foreach ($columns as $key => $value) {
   $value=preg_replace('/\D/','', $value);
    }

 $data=array_combine($escapedHeader, $columns);
  $id=$data['id'];
 $details=$data['details'];
 $postingdate=$data['postingdate'];
  $description=$data['description'];
 $amount=$data['amount'];
  $type=$data['type'];
  $slip=$data['slip'];
  $name=$data['name'];
  $job=$data['job'];
  $addchecks=Checks::firstOrNew(['id'=>$id,'details'=>$details]);
  $addchecks->postingdate=$postingdate;
   $addchecks->description=$description;
   $addchecks->amount=$amount;
   $addchecks->type=$type;
   $addchecks->slip=$slip;
   $addchecks->name=$name;
    $addchecks->job=$job;
    $addchecks->save();
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About first problem:
- The first problem is in database I have id columns witch will be auto increment and not exists in csv file, and there are 2 others columns (name,job) are not exist on csv file but want them to be empty in database and end user will fill these fields.

Let's split it to two parts:
1. I have id columns witch will be auto increment and not exists in csv file.
This is not a problem, because database usually have auto increment field which you can skip during insert, so db will put id by itself.
2. there are 2 others columns (name,job) are not exist on csv file but want them to be empty in database and end user will fill these fields.
You can set this fields `nullable()` in db which allows you to skip fields during insert.
For example, in your migration:

```
//Default table creation/update function
....
 $table->string('name')->nullable();
// If you'd like to specify some other value, you can do it like this
 $table->string('name')->nullbale()->default('some value');
```

The same is true for job field.

About second problem:
- Second problem is the format date in database is yyyy-mm-dd and its different to csv
You can read more about [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) or built-in [method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), but to keep it simple, you can just transform your csv date value as string to rearrange values. For example:

```
$postingDate=$data['postingdate'];
$formattedDate = explode('-', $postingDate);
// And here you rearrange received values.
```